Firebase sending notification Not working in laravel
I'm using Laravel version 7.0.1.
Accidently My push notification service with Laravel is not working without any changes in my code and Firebase settings.
Here I provided my function of sending push notification and also mentioned the error.
It will be great if anyone can help me out.
This is my Laravel version 7.0.1 's Code
function sendNotification($data)
    {
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $serverKey = getenv('FIREBASE_SERVERKEY');

        $encodedData = json_encode($data);
        $headers = [
            'Authorization:key=' . $serverKey,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encodedData);
        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        // Decode the result
    $response = json_decode($result, true);

    // Check for errors in the FCM response
    if (isset($response['error'])) {
        die('FCM error: ' . $response['error']);
    }

    // Optionally, print the entire response for debugging
    dd($response);
        return true;
    }

**And I'm getting this error.
**
Getting this Error While Sending The notification

array:5 [ // app/Http/Controllers/Api/BaseController.php:254
  "multicast_id" => 830795794971026898
  "success" => 0
  "failure" => 1
  "canonical_ids" => 0
  "results" => array:1 [
    0 => array:1 [
      "error" => "DeprecatedApi"
    ]
  ]
]```


Ok. So what's your question? Is there something about "deprecated API" you didn't understand? Did you check the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref quite clearly says that this old API is being removed. You need to move to using the newer API

Apps using the deprecated FCM legacy APIs for HTTP and XMPP should migrate to the HTTP v1 API at the earliest opportunity. Sending messages (including upstream messages) with those APIs was deprecated on June 20, 2023, and shutdown begins on July 22, 2024.
For More Detail.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
